# The Windows Subsystem system process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I'm experiencing the weirdest BSOD in my entire experience with Windows.

I don't have a screenshot of my error but this looks pretty much the same:

[image]

The strange thing is that this BSOD seems to be happening after the system has been idle for some time (20 minutes to a couple of hour), but it doesn't happen all the times; in fact, it happens very rarely (maybe one or two times a month). I'm unable to reproduce it or find any triggering cause or any pattern. Nothing.

Here some system info

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1 (all Windows updates installed)
- MOBO: Asus z87 Deluxe
- CPU: Intel 4770k (OC @ 4.2 GHZ, all C states activated, EIST activated)
- RAM: 16 GB g.skill TridentX @ 2133MHZ (XMP)
- VGA: Nvidia GTS 250 (with latest drivers)
- Main drive: Samsung 830 256GB

The CPU is watercooled and idle core temperatures (which is when this BSOD happens) are around 25-28 °C.

I know i should test my system with base clocks first, but how am i supposed to conclude the problems is OC with an unreproducible BSOD?

Edit: forgot to mention that Event Viewer is not helping me at all, all i ever found there about this error is the exact time the BSOD kicked in. Additionally, no memory dump is collected even though i have an active pagefile (which is required to collect memory dumps).

Comment: Have you run a memtest on the memory? That is where I would start.

Comment: Yes, i ran tests when i tested the stability of the OC (which was not so long ago): memtest for a couple of passes, prime95 for about a day and linx for 15 passes or so. I could run it again to be sure though.

Comment: You mention your computer being idle so it might be related to different states processor is switching to when not being used (downclocking). This can be impacted by RAM/CPU configurations that happen during downclocking of CPU.I remember on 4550k there was something related to C1 States, but I don't remember. I would google for specific Mobo/CPU combination problems on overclocker sites.

Comment: **I actually would return the CPU to the stock settings before I did anything.**  Your overclock might not be as stable as you believe it is.

Comment: Ok, i followed your advice and went full stock; then, during these days, i let my system go idle on purpose every now and then and 10 minutes ago the same BSOD kicked in. What now? I'm tempted to do a format and OS reinstall, but i would like to try something else before going this drastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, i did a complete format/OS reinstall of Windows 7 some time after posting this question. Never seen this BSOD again since.